# My code does not display when its < 0 in C

Tags: c

```
    double discriminant (double a, double b, double c){

    double disc;

    disc = sqrt((b*b) - (4 * a * c));

    if(disc < 0){

        printf("Discriminant is negatief");
    }
    if(disc == 0){
           printf("Het is gelijk aan %.4lf ", disc);
    }
    if(disc > 0){
           printf("Het is groter dan 0. Het is namelijk %.4lf ", disc);
    }
```

So up here is my function to calculate the discriminant. I am trying to do the abc formula. However... when my sqrt is smaller then 0 it does not print my printf... what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not how you compute the discriminant. There's one unneeded operation in there.

Comment: Even je wiskundeboek goed nalezen ;)

Comment: It's very unlikely that you'll ever get exactly `0.0` as a result.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What is the unneeded operation if I may ask? However that is not my problem here, the problem is that it is not doing what I ask in the if(disc < 0)

Comment: @edheal he's talking about the discriminant... not the whole abc. That would be missing more actually.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding but i am trying to get the discriminant to work in this code only.

Comment: Yes, it is the answer. If you don't de the calculation right, it doesn't work.

Comment: @edheal that's the whole point. There shouldn't be a square root for determining the discriminatant.. trying to make him realize that.

Comment: @Rz_iSuck I tried to give a subtle hint, but okay. [You don't need the square root.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)

Comment: Alright I see.. my math isn't the best. Thanks, will give it a shot! @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If *a*, *b*, and *c* are the coefficients of a quadratic equation with a double zero (*b* ² = 4 *ac*), and `a`, `b`, and `c` are the `double` values nearest *a*, *b*, and *c*, respectively, and they and *b*² are within the normal range of `double`, then I expect `b*b - 4*a*c` will often be exactly zero.

Comment: It works. I did have to remove the sqrt... thanks guys. Learned some math today i guess :D

Answer (score 1):

what you sqrt a negative value, the return will be nan. just as
when divided by 0, we get nan

nan is a special value, compare it with other values will all fail.